# Multiple AJAX requests give inconsistent database updates

Tags: php, ajax

I have a sortable list using JQueryUI and use the JQuery Each function to save the order using an AJAX request to a basic PHP file.  The requests seem to be fine (Firebug console) but not every one is being saved by the PHP file, worse of all it doesn't seem to be consistent, some id's are more likely to fail but this seems to be related to their position in the list!  It's really strange, any ideas?

I have tried GET/POST, sync/async, made no difference.

Javascript

```
function SaveChanges() {
        priority = 0;
        $("#p_menu li").each(function() {
           if($(this).attr("class") != "range") {
               $.ajax({"url": "lib/product-menu-save.php", "data": "pm_id="+this.id+"&priority="+priority, "type": "GET"});
               priority++;
           }
        });
    }
```

PHP file

```
<?php

require_once '../includes/adminsession.php';
require_once '../lib/mysql.php';

$pm_id = $_GET['pm_id'];
$pm_priority = str_pad($_GET['priority'], 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

$save_stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE products SET priority = ? WHERE id = ?");
$save_stmt->bind_param('si', $pm_priority, $pm_id);
if(!$save_stmt->execute()) echo $save_stmt->error; else echo 'SUCCESS';
```

The data looks fine going into the AJAX request and SUCCESS is returned for every request.  There are around 60 items if that is relevant.

Comment: instead of doing 60 AJAX requests, why don't you create a list and submit it with one request ?

Comment: As a JSON string?  Any reason why it isn't working as 60 requests?  Or is it just a recommendation.  Performance isn't an issue but changing the method might just make it work.  Has me stumped this one!

Comment: JSON, two comma-seperated parameters (*one for ids and one for priorities*), any way you can think that will minimize the client-server communication..

Comment: Found the problem now, there is an error in the way the list is generated which adds a couple of duplicated items, therefore over-writing the priority if one is moved up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send the ids as a list in order to minimize the AJAX requests to a single one.
(*since you will be sending all ids together you do not need to send the priority.. you can handle that server-side*)

```
function SaveChanges() {
    var id_list = [];
    $("#p_menu li").each(function() {
       if($(this).attr("class") != "range") {
          id_list.push( this.id );
       }
    });
    $.ajax({
             url  : 'lib/product-menu-save.php', 
             data : {ids: id_list}, 
             type : 'POST'
          });
}
```

and (*something like this, as i am not proficient in PHP*)

```
$save_stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE products SET priority = ? WHERE id = ?");

$pm_priority_value = 0;

foreach ($_POST['ids'] as $pm_id) {

   $pm_priority = str_pad($pm_priority_value, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

   $save_stmt->bind_param('si', $pm_priority, $pm_id);
   if(!$save_stmt->execute()) echo $save_stmt->error; else echo 'SUCCESS';

   $pm_priority_value++;
}
```